# Method not found: 'System.Threading.Monitor.Enter' with Nhibernate, Mono & SQLite

Tags: c#, nhibernate, sqlite, mono

I'm trying to port an existing NHibernate project from using MySQL to using SQLite and I'm running into an interesting error when I try and run the tests:

```
1) ProductRepository_Fixture : System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'System.Threading.Monitor.Enter'.
```

I've tried googling this error with no luck. I assume that I must be missing a reference of some kind - but I can't figure out what...

This is all being done on Mono.

Any ideas at all what I'm missing?

**Update:** Have since found a further error message that I hadn't spotted before:

```
.Missing method System.Type::op_Equality(Type,Type) in assembly /usr/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll, referenced in assembly /tmp/nunit20/ShadowCopyCache/4606_634431542912600100/Tests/assembly/shadow/fa3c43db/9b71732a_614d30f1_00000001/Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll
Missing method System.Threading.Monitor::Enter(object,bool&) in assembly /usr/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll, referenced in assembly /tmp/nunit20/ShadowCopyCache/4606_634431542912600100/Tests/assembly/shadow/fa3c43db/9b71732a_614d30f1_00000001/Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll
F    Missing method System.Threading.Monitor::Enter(object,bool&) in assembly /usr/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll, referenced in assembly /tmp/nunit20/ShadowCopyCache/4606_634431542912600100/Tests/assembly/shadow/fa3c43db/9b71732a_614d30f1_00000001/Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll
Missing method System.Threading.Monitor::Enter(object,bool&) in assembly /usr/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll, referenced in assembly /tmp/nunit20/ShadowCopyCache/4606_634431542912600100/Tests/assembly/shadow/fa3c43db/9b71732a_614d30f1_00000001/Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll
.F.F.F.FMissing method System.Threading.Monitor::Enter(object,bool&) in assembly /usr/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll, referenced in assembly /tmp/nunit20/ShadowCopyCache/4606_634431542912600100/Tests/assembly/shadow/fa3c43db/9b71732a_614d30f1_00000001/Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you referencing the correct profile? Unfortunately the error message doesn't specify which `Monitor.Enter` method is missing (there are several), but I do know that some were added to the .NET 4.0 profile. If this is the case, then you need to compile your code with `dmcs` to reference the .NET 4.0 profile members; if you use `gmcs` you're targeting the .NET 2.0/3.5 profile.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm building this with Monodevelop and all the projects have the runtime target of Mono 4.0 - is that what you mean?

Comment: Are you sure you're building _everything_ with the 4.0 runtime target? I'd expect to see those errors if you referenced a 4.0 assembly when building a 2.0 app, but vice versa should work...

Comment: Every single project under Properties/Build/Runtime has a target of 4.0.  But I do take your point - it should be fine...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with running NUnit under Mono for test dlls compiled with .Net v4.0.

I solved this by specifying the runtime when running mono with:

`mono --runtime=v4.0 YourProgram.exe`

For NUnit to work in conjunction with msbuild, there's a config file you can modify, see this post:
http://www.dotnetjobsandcareers.com/running-nunit-tests-on-net-4-assemblies-with-msbuild/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by specifically referencing the 2.0 version of the Mono.Data.SQLite.dll - not a very elegant or good solution, but it'll do as a workaround.

Would still be interested to hear if anyone has any better suggestions though...